# Question about out-of-scope FFI MemoryPointer that is returned from a method

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, ffi

Let's say I have the following ruby code that uses FFI library:

```
  class SimpleStruct < FFI::Struct
    layout :value, :pointer
  end
  
  class Test1
    def self.foo(s)
      result = FFI::MemoryPointer.from_string(s)

      result
    end

    def self.bar(s)
      simple_struct = SimpleStruct.new
      value = FFI::MemoryPointer.from_string(s)
      simple_struct[:value] = value

      simple_struct
    end
  end
  
  
  class Test2
    def self.testing
      a = Test1.foo('test')
      b = Test1.bar('test')

      puts a.read_string, b[:value].read_string
    end
  end
```

The FFI wiki mentions `When a MemoryPointer goes out of scope, the memory is freed up as part of the garbage collection process`. In the `Test1` class above, `foo` method returns a MemoryPointer and `bar` method returns an FFI struct that holds MemoryPointer. The `testing` method in `Test2` class calls these methods and stores the returned values in variable `a` and `b` respectively.

My question is when the MemoryPointer created inside `foo` and `bar` method will be garbage collected in this case? Is it when the MemoryPointer variable goes out of scope in `foo` and `bar` methods or when the local variable `a` or `b` (that references the MemoryPointer returned from the `foo`/`bar` methods) goes out of scope in `testing` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `FFI::Struct#[]=` takes care of this. I didn't check it in the sources, but I've added some checks into your code and it looks so.

```
require 'ffi'

class SimpleStruct < FFI::Struct
  layout :value, :pointer
end

class Test1
  def self.foo(s)
    puts "foo is called"
    result = FFI::MemoryPointer.from_string(s)
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(result, proc { puts "foo result is garbage collected" })
    result
  end

  def self.bar(s)
    puts "bar is called"
    simple_struct = SimpleStruct.new
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(s, proc { puts "bar result is garbage collected" })
    value = FFI::MemoryPointer.from_string(s)
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(s, proc { puts "bar result[:value] is garbage collected" })
    simple_struct[:value] = value

    simple_struct
  end

  def self.baz(s)
    puts "baz is called"
    simple_struct = {}
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(s, proc { puts "baz result is garbage collected" })
    value = FFI::MemoryPointer.from_string(s)
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(s, proc { puts "baz result[:value] is garbage collected" })
    simple_struct[:value] = value

    simple_struct
  end
end

class Test2
  def self.testing
    puts "testing is started"
    a = Test1.foo('foo')
    b = Test1.bar('bar')
    c = Test1.baz('baz')

    puts a.read_string, b[:value].read_string, c[:value].read_string
    puts "testing is finished"
  end
end

GC.stress

Test2.testing

# testing is started
# foo is called
# bar is called
# baz is called
# foo
# bar
# baz
# testing is finished
# baz result is garbage collected
# baz result[:value] is garbage collected
# bar result is garbage collected
# bar result[:value] is garbage collected
# foo result is garbage collected
```

A pointer is only garbage collected when the struct is garbage-collected, as is the case with a hash.